# Mongodb update all the documents with unique id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native

I have collection with name `products` with almost 100k documents. I want to introduce a new key called `secondaryKey` with unique value [`uuid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)  in all the documents.
I do this using `nodejs`.

Problem I am facing:-

When I try the below query,

```
db.collection('products').updateMany({},{"$set":{secondaryKey: uuid()}});
```

Here it updates all the documents with same `uuid` value,

I try with loop to update document one by one,but here issues is I don't have `filter` value in `updateOne` because I want to update all the documents.

Can anyone please help me here.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using MongoDB version >= 4.4 You can try this:

```js
db.products.updateMany(
    {},
    [
        {
            $set: {
                secondaryKey: {
                    $function: {
                        body: function() {
                            return UUID().toString().split('"')[1];
                        },
                        args: [],
                        lang: "js"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Output

```js
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("..."),
    "secondaryKey": "f41b15b7-a0c5-43ed-9d15-69dbafc0ed29"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("..."),
    "secondaryKey": "50ae7248-a92e-4b10-be7d-126b8083ff64"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("..."),
    "secondaryKey": "fa778a1a-371b-422a-b73f-8bcff865ad8e"
  }
]
```

Comment: Btw, This question brought me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66894033/set-id-to-a-new-uuid-using-addfields

Comment: This only works if security.javascriptEnabled is enabled which is a requirement and not preferable method.
"For a mongos instance, see security.javascriptEnabled configuration option or the --noscripting command-line option starting in MongoDB 4.4."

Answer (score 1):

Since it's not the same value you want to put in each document you have to use the loop.

In your loop, you have to update the current document of the iteration. So you have to filter with the `_id` in the `updateOne`

Comment: any way, we can achieve through `updateMany`  by just incrementing the `secondaryKey`, I can use `uuid` later as well, just wanted a unquie `secondaryKey` for each document, because looping will be heavier process.

Answer (score 0):

The above reply didn't work for me. Plus, it compromises security when you enable javascript on your database (see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) $function and javascript enabling on database). The best way is to not overload your server, do your work on local as below:

```
const { nanoid, customAlphabet } = require('nanoid') 

async function asdf() {


const movies = await client.db("localhost").collection("productpost");
var result2 = []

let result = await movies.find({}).toArray()
result.forEach(element => {
    const nanoid = customAlphabet('1234567890', 10)
    console.log(element.price)
    element.price = 4
    element.id = nanoid()
    result2.push(element)
});
console.log("out reult2", result2)
await movies.deleteMany({})
await movies.insertMany(result2) 
})
```

It will delete any objects on your collections and update with the new ones. Using [nanoid](https://github.com/ai/nanoid) as uniqueids.

This is the database object array after adding unique id:

```
{  "_id": {    "$oid": "334a98519a20b05c20574dd1"  },  "attach": "[\"http://localhost:8000/be/images/2022/4/bitfinicon.png\"]",  "title": "jkn jnjn",  "description": "jnjn",  "price": 4,  "color": "After viewing I am 48.73025772956596% more satisfied with life.",  "trademark": "",  "category": "[]",  "productstate": "Published",  "createdat": {    "$date": "2022-04-03T17:40:54.743Z"  },  "language": "en"}
```

P.S: Please backup your collection before doing this or filter the array on your needs for not going through all collection.