# Set _id to a new UUID using $addFields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, uuid

Well, someone done goofed. Wasn't me, but I get to fix it. What I need to do, is replace the `_id` of each and every document in the collection with a new UUID.

My plan was aggregating the entire collection, use `$addFields` to replace the `_id`, then merge it back into itself, replacing the records. Fortunately, there is a secondary (composite) key I can use for merging, so I'm good there — *I think, because I haven't gotten there yet.*

The problem I face is generating a unique (that's kinda the point of it) UUID during the `$addFields` stage.

```js
db.foo.agregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            // I really just need the UUID string itself, hence the split
            '_id': UUID().toString().split('"')[1]
        }
    }
    // here's where the merge would go
])
```

The problem here is that `UUID()` is called only once, so I get all the same IDs. That's not quite what I want.

Now the tedious way would be to do this one by one, from a loop. But is there a way to do this from within an aggregation pipeline in one go?

---

*Now I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66688549/2936460) asking basically the same question, but it was solved by not using an UUID, using sequential keys instead, so it really isn't an answer to my question.*

Comment: This is much better approach avoiding security issues when enabling javascript on your database. Please see the asnwer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71733315/12002600

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this answer is just to generate unique `UUID`s by calling `UUID()` from a [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/). Try this:

```js
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            _id: {
                $function: {
                    body: function() {
                        return UUID().toString().split('"')[1];
                    },
                    args: [],
                    lang: "js"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

btw, its only works in MongoDB version >= 4.4.
Output:

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "5dc9316a-50a8-4013-8090-06fc66cdce9f",
    "dummy" : "data"
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "062ebc8f-4455-4a81-a9e0-34f6c7132cab",
    "dummy" : "data"
},

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "94eef4b8-9c0e-4910-a1cb-58443a63a036",
    "dummy" : "data"
}
```

Comment: Yes, that did it! Making a function that returned the UUID was the trick that did it; the generate UUIDs weren't _weird_, but all the same. This solved it.

Comment: I got this message: `$function not allowed in this atlas tier`. Is this was available for all tiers last year or is it recent?

Comment: Sorry I wrote that query in local never tried in cloud. Check this answer if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66688549/mongodb-update-all-the-documents-with-unique-id/71733315#71733315

Answer (score 1):

If what you need to do is

> What I need to do, is replace the _id of each and every document in the collection with a new UUID.

... and you can use ObjectIds instead of UUIDs, then:

- Project out the _id
- $out into a new collection

The server should generate new _ids for each document during the insert.

Then:

- Drop the original collection
- Rename the new collection into the original name

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, but unfortunately they _need_ to be UUIDs.

Comment: After this is done apply a transform to convert objectids to uuids?